# What are the software tools to view the video on Android from the Linux server?

Tags: docker, video, android

I have a Debian 10 remote server on the local network. On this server there is a directory `~/MyVideos`. This directory containing video files that I want to play (to watch) on Android tablet. The files are in `.mkv` and `.mp4` format.

What are the programs for this purpose for both sides: client (Android) and server (Linux)? Preferably open source.

P.S. I can install the server in Docker Container (in my Debian 10 local network server) if necessary.

Comment: Any http server (like apache) on the server and any internet browser on the android tablet. Assuming that the videos are not in some "special" format (in which case you have a different problem)

Comment: Video formats is `.mkv` and `.mp4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VLC on Android supports SFTP, so nothing more than SSH on the server is needed (at least on the rare occasion I do access videos on my PC from my phone, this combination works fine).

Comment: As I understand, unfortunately, the rewind of the video on the client side of this method is not available.

Comment: I don't know about *rewinding*, but seeking does work well enough for me (with the obvious delay induced by having to load that portion of the file over the network). Anyway, that's irrelevant, since rewinding was not mentioned in the question.